# where to add a global function in coldbox to call in a view

Tags: coldbox

Where in coldbox would you add a function that would be visible in your view thats global
for instance, i want to create a function that replaces spaces with hyphens for a URL

```
public string function makeUrl(url) {
replace bit here    
    return URL;
}
```

where would you store this?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a view helper.

This is a page with that can contain user defined ColdFusion functions. Your view will have automatic access to it.

More details here:
https://coldbox.ortusbooks.com/the-basics/layouts-and-views/views/view-helpers

However, for your specific case, you may want to consider using JavaScript instead.

Answer (score 0):

Create a **viewsHelper.cfm** file and add your global function.

also add your viewsHelper.cfm path in your **config > coldbox.cfc** file.

See link  https://coldbox.ortusbooks.com/the-basics/layouts-and-views/helpers-udfs